# Problema con ORDER BY [ASC | DESC]

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un problema con el ORDER BY que no consigo entender porque no funciona, y seguramente es una estupidez, pero no consigo encontrar la estupidez.

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM webla_solicitudinfo ORDER BY 'IDSolicitud' ASC
```

He probado a poner IDSolicitud sin las '', he probado cambiando ASC por DESC a ver si notaba algún cambio, pero nada.

Mi intención es listar una base de datos de Solicitudes de información por orden de llegada, siendo los últimos en llegar los primeros de la lista. Por ello los ordeno por la ID de la solicitud, pero no lo llega a filtrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pepe Gordillo debería salir el primero, al ser el último en solicitar información.

Esta es la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas la tabla ordenada por fecha en la columna fecha de la tabla en si, que me imagino es un datatable? y que por eso no te esta respetando el orden que viene desde la base de datos, me imagino que te esta recordando el ordenamiento.

Comment: Como ha dicho @HectorScesa, tienes la tabla con un filtro en fecha. De tal forma que no importa el orden de la bbdd, la tabla lo machaca.

Comment: Opción 1: Quitar todos los filtros que el framework web coloca y cambiar la consulta de forma DESC. Opción 2: Si quieres que el cambio solo sea visual, puedes quitar el ORDER BY de la consulta y configurar el orden desde el framework web. Puedes darnos mas detalles de lo que usas, para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Vale como creía, era esa estupidez tan grande. El plugin de datatables los estaba ordenando directamente. Muchas gracias a los dos por la ayuda.  @HectorScesa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema residía en el plugin Datatables que filtraba automáticamente por fecha de manera ASC. He cambiado el filtro por DESC añadiendo la siguiente parte de código en la etiqueta

```
data-order='[[ 1, "desc" ]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM webla_solicitudinfo ORDER BY IDSolicitud DESC;
```

Si usas php tb puedes recorrer elen array que te devuelve la consulta desde el ultimo elemento hasta el primero para mostrarlo, o hacer un sort, hay nuchas variantes